# Datatypes and order of constructors

Tags: dafny

Is there a difference between the following definitions?

```
datatype Nat = S(Nat) | Z
```

And

```
datatype Nat = Z | S(Nat)
```

I would expect no, but interestingly enough, the following code compiles fine with the first definition, but not with the second.

```
function natToDay(n : Nat) : Day
  decreases n
{
  match n {
    case Z                      => Monday
    case S(Z)                   => Tuesday
    case S(S(Z))                => Wednesday
    case S(S(S(Z)))             => Thursday
    case S(S(S(S(Z))))          => Friday
    case S(S(S(S(S(Z)))))       => Saturday
    case S(S(S(S(S(S(Z))))))    => Sunday
    case S(S(S(S(S(S(S(k))))))) => natToDay(k)
  }
}

lemma {:induction n} proof(n : Nat)
  ensures natToDay(n) == Sunday    ==> natToDay(n) == Sunday
  ensures natToDay(n) == Saturday  ==> natToDay(S(n)) == Sunday
  ensures natToDay(n) == Friday    ==> natToDay(S(S(n))) == Sunday
  ensures natToDay(n) == Thursday  ==> natToDay(S(S(S(n)))) == Sunday
  ensures natToDay(n) == Wednesday ==> natToDay(S(S(S(S(n))))) == Sunday
  ensures natToDay(n) == Tuesday   ==> natToDay(S(S(S(S(S(n)))))) == Sunday
  ensures natToDay(n) == Monday    ==> natToDay(S(S(S(S(S(S(n))))))) == Sunday
{}
```

The first datatype definition produces:

```
Dafny program verifier finished with 2 verified, 0 errors
Wrote textual form of target program to test.cs
```

The second one produces:

```
/Users/boro/Desktop/dafny/test.dfy(27,0): Error: A postcondition might not hold on this return path.
/Users/boro/Desktop/dafny/test.dfy(21,54): Related location: This is the postcondition that might not hold.
Execution trace:
...
```

Comment: Btw, I see you have written `decreases n` and `{:induction n}` explicitly in your code. That's fine, but it's also not necessary. The Dafny IDE shows you these two as information, saying it has filled in those for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's not supposed to be any difference between the two. Please report this problem on https://github.com/dafny-lang/dafny/issues.